# Integer roots with two variables

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What are all integral values of a constant $a$ such that
>   $$(a+1)x^2-(a^2+1)x+2a^3-6=0$$
>   has two integral roots?

I've seen questions like this before, so my first instinct was to use Vieta's. Let $p$ and $q$ be roots,
$$p+q=\frac{a^2+1}{a+1}=a-1+\frac{2}{a+1}$$
$$pq=\frac{2a^3-6}{a+1}=2a^2-2a+2-\frac{8}{a+1}$$
Then you could try to create a diopantine equations with p and q, but I don't know how.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you wrote

If $a=-1$ then the equation becomes

$$2x=-8 $$
the unique root is $x=-4$.

If $a\ne -1$, the sum of the roots is

$$S=a-1+\frac{2}{a+1}$$
thus $ a+1 $ should divide $2$.
so, $a+1\in \{1, -1, 2,-2\}$.

$\;$And this gives
$$a\in \{0,-2,1,-3\}.$$

the product will take the values

$$P=\frac{2a^3-6}{a+1}=-6,22,-2,30.$$

For example, when $ a=0,$

$$S=1 \;\text{ and }\; P=-6$$
the roots satisfy
$$x^2-x-6=0$$
thus
$$x_1=-3 \;  \text{ and } \; x_2=2$$
The answer to your question is necessarily
$$\boxed{a\in \{-3,-2,-1,0,1\}}$$

You should now check if these values are sufficient.

Comment: There is small mistake I believe. When $a=-2$ the equation is 
$$-x^2-5x-22=0$$
which has complex roots. Same for $a=-3$. Otherwise, nice solution!

Comment: @Baker013273213 Thanks for your remark. What i gave is just necessary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Then it discriminat must be a perfect square:

$$(a^2+1)^2-4(a+1)(2a^3-6)=d^2$$

so

$$ -7a^4 -8a^3+2a^2+24a+25 \geq 0$$

or $$ 25 \geq a^2(7a^2-2)+8a(a^2-3)$$

...

Answer (score 1):

If $p$, $q$, $a$ are integers, then, by your first equation, $\frac{2}{a+1}$ is an integer.

The only way for this to be true is when $a+1$ divides 2, i.e.

$$
a+1 = -2, -1, 1, 2
$$

Now you only have four cases, just whack them all haha